# Running Virtualbox Windows 7 VM: GUI vs Headless + RDP Which is more efficient?

Tags: virtualbox, performance, remote-desktop, virtualization

Host: Debian 9.3 Stretch
Guest: Windows 7 (uses an existing partition as disk)

I am currently opening Virtualbox GUI and turning on the VM and using that GUI. I was wondering if is there any gain (less consumption of resources on the host) if I start the VM as a headless using VBoxManage and connect to the VM using remote desktop. Is this true? Is the difference significant?

Comment: Headless is mainly designed for VMs that don't use a graphical interface (dedicated server VMs). From the quick Googling I've done, it looks like Headless runs the VM in the same way, except it doesn't display the graphical output in a window. This probably means that performance would be the same, both in the guest and host.

Comment: I realize that this is out of scope for the question, but if you *really want* the graphical output, you may consider tunneling an actual VGA adapter to your VM - check IOMMU and VFIO if these apply to you (I don't think it works with VirtualBox though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Headless VMs do not display the graphical output of the running virtual machine on the host machine.  This means you will save a *miniscule* amount of resources not displaying the output on the host machine.  However, in the case of Windows 7, it requires a graphical output or it will fail.  This means Windows 7 is still processing and outputting its graphics, its just not being displayed.

Comment: That is unfortunate. What is the point of running in "headless" mode as a VM if not to reduce resource consumption?